# Retaining permissions when copying a folder

Tags: permissions, cp

I am having an issue where I have Parent folder that has full permissions.. I can create a new folder and that folder also has full permissions. However when I copy a folder over to this parent Directory and try to create a new directory to this copied directory. it loses all permissions.. is there a way to retain permissions to the copied folders..

Answer (score 14):

Yes.  When copying using `cp`, the `-p` option preserves permissions.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html

```
      -p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

       --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
              preserve the specified attributes (default:
              mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional
              attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

Comment: I normally use `cp -a` to preserve modtime as well.  (And to enable recursive copying, in the rare case I'm using cp for that instead of rsync to preserve hardlinks.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Note that `-p` already preserves timestamps and `-a` is a non-POSIX extension.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to [steve's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639110/117549), you can use `rsync`.

```
 rsync -avhH /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

The `a` switch preserves permissions, modify times, ownership, and also makes it recursive and copies symlinks. `v` makes it verbose and `h` and `H` respectively make the output human readable and copies hardlinks.

The `a` is important as that does what you want.

Comment: `-a` is also available for `cp` with the same meaning

Answer (score 3):

I like a tar pipe for retaining user/group ownership and permissions, and for tar's flexibility for defining which files to copy

```
tar cf - -C sourcedir -T filelist | tar xvf - -C targetdir
```